# Any way to get localized strings for `hour`, `day`, etc?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I know that [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) has properties like [DayNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames) and [MonthNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames) in your localized language.

But is there a way to get generic words like `hour` or `day` in localized language too?

Comment: No, .NET only has enough to make ToString() work.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. There is so much that `System.Globalization` does, that it sometimes it is difficult to remember what it doesn't.